# How to gather information from end user in sharepoint 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I want to get different field values of lists from different users at step wise. How can I prompt users to enter the information of required field using workflow?

For Example: I have document library with CVs Following are stages

- filtering - user needs to select if shortlisted or not - udpate in the list
- shortlisted - user needs to enter the date of interview - update time
  in list
- Interview - result is pass/failed  - update status in list
- ask documents - result pending/received - update status to document
  collection
- etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems hard to do with vanilla SharePoint, but because we have the ability to customize the forms of libraries with InfoPath, it's actually quite easy.

First off, you'll want to decide if you just want to customize the forms of an existing document library or if instead, you want to build the base as an InfoPath form library. There are advantages to using form library as the base. In your example's case, the ability to attach multiple documents to the same form, would be beneficial.

Simply use a hidden field to keep track of the status of the item's workflow. Upon reaching a new status, a workflow (built with SharePoint Designer) would notify the applicable participants via email. (Define the participants for each phase in SharePoint lists so that values can easily be updated when someone changed positions etc.)

When a given participant clicks on the link in the email (provided by the workflow to link to the next phase (use views for phases)) they are taken directly to where action is required. 
Protect other non current action fields that displays necessary information (such as other participants' comments) by making their respective fields read only based on the phase value in your hidden field.

This way, you have complete control over the data and the flow of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'send email activity' to notify the users at different stages on the status change. You can add the Form Link in the email so that users can navigate to list Form using that link. YOu may need to create a custom form to collect the values for the different fields at different stages by users.